# MongoDB query - pass the function to the Model.find()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have issue with querying MongoDB (Mongoose) by passing the `function` as parameter in `Model.find()` -> like this `Model.find(searchCondition)`. I hope that you can help me.

```
// Fetching patients from the database
exports.getPatients = (req, res, next) => {
    const criterionSearchCategory = req.query.kriterijumPretrage;
    const ageSearchCategory = req.query.kriterijumGodina;
    const searchInputValue = req.query.pojamPretrage;

    console.log({ [criterionSearchCategory]: { [ageSearchCategory]: Number([searchInputValue]) }});

    // Patient search condition, based on selected option from select dropdown
    function searchCondition() {
        if (criterionSearchCategory == 'undefined') {
            return {};
        } else if (criterionSearchCategory == 'age') {
            return { [criterionSearchCategory]: { [ageSearchCategory] : Number([searchInputValue]) }}
        } else {
            return { [criterionSearchCategory]: { $in: [ "/^" + searchInputValue + "/i" ]}}
        }
    }

   ...
```

```
    const patientQuery = Patient.find(searchCondition);
```

```
getPatients(patientsPerPage: number, currentPage: number, criterionSearchCategory: string, searchInputValue: string, ageSearchCategory: any) {
        const queryParams = `?pacijenataPoStranici=${patientsPerPage}&trenutnaStranica=${currentPage}&kriterijumPretrage=${criterionSearchCategory}&pojamPretrage=${searchInputValue}&kriterijumGodina=${ageSearchCategory}`;
        this.http
            .get<{ message: string, patients: any, maxPatients: number }>( BACKEND_URL + queryParams)
            // Execute map on every data that makes it through Observable stream
            .pipe(map((patientData) => {
```

**I want to menton when I pass the query params manually**, for example `const patientQuery = Patient.find({ age: { '$gt': 30 } });` appropriate patients will be fetched correctly , but when I pass the function , like this `const patientQuery = Patient.find(searchCondition);` then does not work.

The first question, is it possible to pass the function as parameter like this?

Any suggestion will be appreciate. Thank you

Comment: I fail to see how `const patientQuery = Patient.find({ age: { '$gt': 30 } });` differs from `const patientQuery = Patient.find({ age: { '$gt': 30 } });` in the "I want to.." paragraph.

Comment: Ah, about the function as a parameter - no  you cannot. The function expects an object. You should respect function signature since you don't own it but you always can write an adapter to accept function as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I achieve that?

Comment: hmm, achieve what? The paragraph  "I want to.."  makes no sense to me. You posted 2 identical code snippets stating that one of them works and the other "does not work".

Comment: Ohh sorry, I saw this, my mistake. I want to say - when I pass the query params manually, for example const patientQuery = Patient.find({ age: { '$gt': 30 } }); appropriate patients will be fetched correctly , but when I pass the function , like this const patientQuery = Patient.find(searchCondition); then does not work.

Comment: Yes, it should not. Functions have signatures - list of parameters they expect, often with specific type of the values. One cannot send anything as a parameter and expect it to work. Similarly you cannot get a square root from a string, or load a web page using an image instead of a url. It's responsibility of the software engineer to learn what parameters the function accepts and call the function with expected arguments.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you help me ?